# Calculate average of based on weekly dates EXCEL

Tags: excel, select, excel-formula

I am completely new at excel and I have an assignment involving 12k of rows. Basically, I have to calculate the average of the all the values from the same date. These dates follow the arithmetic succession with a difference of 7. Therefore, dates will be like 2/2/52; 2/9/52; 2/16/52; 2/23/53 etc. I know how to find the average of a specific group of values, but selecting one group of values at a time to find the average will take forever because there must be about 5k of different dates. Therefore, I was looking for an automated way that allows me to find the average without going to select the values every single time. The following is an example of the spreadsheet that I am dealing with:

DATE------------------VALUE

2/2/52----------------3.5

2/2/52----------------3.4

2/2/52----------------2.5

2/9/52----------------4.5

2/9/52----------------3.6

2/16/52---------------2.4

2/16/52---------------4.1

2/16/52---------------3.1

2/16/52---------------4.2

2/16/52---------------2.34

Also, please note that the dates do not change in a pattern, meaning dates do not change every n rows.

Comment: check out the `AVERAGEIF` formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect candidate for a PIVOT table.
Here is your data.

```
DATE    VALUE
2/2/1952    3.5
2/2/1952    3.4
2/2/1952    2.5
2/9/1952    4.5
2/9/1952    3.6
2/16/1952   2.4
2/16/1952   4.1
2/16/1952   3.1
2/16/1952   4.2
2/16/1952   2.34
```

Select the data and insert pivot table.
Drag Date into rows
Drag VALUE into VALUES
Drop down on the values - select value settings
and select Average

```
Row Labels  Average of VALUE
2/2/1952    3.133333333
2/9/1952    4.05
2/16/1952   3.228
```

Grand Total 3.364

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Now, my next task is to find the average for each month. How would I do that?

Comment: Easy.
make sure your data (the date column) is formatted as date. Select the column and format it as Date in the number formats.
Once you do that, create the pivot table, as above,
then, in the pivot table,  click on any date value (the averages 1st column) and right click.
Then choose Group
Select Months

Comment: I did you said, but the thing is that my data spans 5 years. When I did what you said, it grouped all my data in 12 months only, as if the data belonged to the same year. I am looking for something like Jan-1952, February- 1952... January-1953, February-1953 etc.